# I want to get input from user in PHP as an array in loop like for or while

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to get an input from a user in PHP in a loop and store it in an array.  But loop print all iterations in one go. And I want the loop to wait for input in one iteration and get value and then execute next iteration like in C++ and Java. it this possible? if yes then how?

If possible in javascript, then that would also be an acceptable solution.

my code is:

```
<?php 
print "<form method=Post action=try.php>";
for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){
    echo "<form action='try1.php' method='post'>"."<input type='text' 
name='link'>";
    echo "<input type='submit' name='link' value='done'>";

}
 ?>
```

Comment: this certainly is possible (to some extend) using JS and AJAX

Comment: can you tell me how ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Present the user with 10 forms in a row, each needed to be filled out before presenting the next?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure that I understand what you are asking for. But if you want to create an array of user inputs you could use Javascript/jQuery. Simply append the array with the input value and clear the field. If you want to process the data with PHP, just send it to the script with AJAX. This might be a good start:

```js
var content = [];

$( '#myForm' ).submit(function( e ) {
 e.preventDefault();
 content.push( $( '.link' ).val() );
  $( '.link' ).val( '' );
  $( '#console' ).html( content.toString() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm" method="post">
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="link" name="link">
    <button type="submit" class="done">Click!</button>
  </div>
</form>


<div id="console"></div>
```

Comment: sir this code is not working in my pc undefined token error

Comment: @Emil Stackoverflow is not supposed to be a coding service, but a place to learn how to code. Please do not encourage people by providing them with ready made code fragment. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this does not work is that PHP in the context of a webserver is request based. When you run your script in the browser, itss executed on the websever from start to finish and then the result (e.g HTML page) is returned to your client.

If you want a more interactive approach you need to implement that in Javascript, which is running on your client and can manipulate the HTML page based on user input. (you can combine Javascript and PHP)

If you want to learn how to do all that the [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/) are a great place to start.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but you will have to use php session to keep track of form click, and store the variable as well

```
<?php 
if(isset($_SESSION['count'])){
    $count = $_SESSION['count'];
}else{
    $count = $_SESSION['count'] = 10;
}

if ($count){
    echo "<form action='try1.php' method='post'>"."<input type='text' 
name='link'>";
    echo "<input type='submit' name='link' value='done'>";
    $_SESSION['count']--;
}
 ?>
```

You also need to use session to keep track of the form response.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not supposed to be a coding service, but a place to learn how to code. Please do not encourage people by providing them with ready made code fragment. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

```
This code should help you.

<html>
    <body>
        <form action='try1.php' method='post'>
            <div class="txt-area">
                <input type='text' name='link[]'>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="button" class="btn-add">+ Add</button>
            </div>
            <input type='submit' name='link' value='done'>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var x = new Array();
    $('.btn-add').on('click', function(){
        $(".txt-area").append("<input type='text' name='link[]' style='display:block'>");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not supposed to be a coding service, but a place to learn how to code. Please do not encourage people by providing them with ready made code fragment.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken ok, i would keep in mind, i am new here.